# How to show that, following function is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, smooth-functions

**Question**: I need to show that, the function defined by,
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
         e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}} & \text{if $|x| < 1$;}\\
        0 & \text{if $|x|≥ 1$.}
     \end{cases}
$$
has continuous derivatives of all order for every $t$

**My attempt**: as for $x>1$ function is defined to be zero. Hence for $x>1$ it has derivative of all orders and all them are Continuous. But for for $x<1$ how to show function is smooth? I am not to calculate those derivatives for $x≤1$? Please anyone help me?

Comment: This function is discontinuous at 0. Are you sure that you've got the intervals right? Or perhaps you meant $e^{1/x}$.

Comment: @ajr. I just edited the question. I had done mistake in typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The composition of smooth functions is smooth, so you only need to check what happens at $x=1$. The right derivative at $1$ is zero. For the left derivative, note that for $x<1$
$$
f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{q_n(x)}{(x^2-1)^{n+1}}\,\exp\Big(\frac1{x^2-1}\Big)
$$
for some polynomial $q_n$. Then
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(x)-0}{x-1}={q_n(x)\,(x+1)}\,\frac1{(x^2-1)^{n+2}}\,\exp\Big(\frac1{x^2-1}\Big).
$$
And
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{(x^2-1)^{n+2}}\,\exp\Big(\frac1{x^2-1}\Big)
=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+2}\,t^{n+2}}{e^t}=0.
$$
So $f^{(n+1)}(1)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much... sir :)

Comment: Sir, i have one query. How you calculated the last limit. I think it is $∞×∞$ form and hence limit goes to $∞$. But, how it is $0$ please help

Comment: It is a limit from the left.